# Audit Log Recommendations for .NET apps using MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, audit

Our team is currently working on a project in which we use .NET web development tools and MongoDB as our database. We are searching for an optimal way to write Audit logs and trails, catch and track user operations (who changed what and when? etc.) and save this data efficiently to our database. Are there any packages (ex. NuGet packages), extensions or anything else that you prefer or have used in similar areas?

I have found one GitHub repository which creates AuditEvent objects to with many customizable fields to keep track of operations and is integrated with almost all of commonly used database technologies. However, the code was hard for me to understand mainly due to my lack of knowledge in C# and .NET in general. The link is below:

(https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.MongoDB/Providers/MongoDataProvider.cs)

If there's a similar, yet simpler alternative that you've used before, please answer the question.[text]

Comment: By defining a middleware you can capture all requests made from here. You can get information such as the user who made the request, the ip address from which the request was made, the response returned and store it in a queue and then save it to mongodb.You can find more detailed information if you search for "middleware logging".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.